# Prevent on getting 0 in input tag type=number

Tags: javascript, html

I store the html elements for the cart table. I can't prevent on getting 0 value on the input id="qtyInput"

here's the javascript code...

```
  var qtyInput = '<input id="qtyInput" class=" text-center" type="number" min="1" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" style="width:50px;" id="qty_value" name="qty_value" value="' + productQty + '"><input type="hidden" id="productId" value="' + productId + '">'
                cartHtml += '<tr><td><img src="../admin/img/product_images/' + productImg + '" style="width:50px"/></td><td>' + productName + '</td><td>' + productPrice + '</td><td>' + productTotal + '</td><td>' + qtyInput + '</td><td>' + deleteBtn + '</td></tr>';
```

ajax code

```
function fetchCartData() {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax_calls/fetch-cart.php',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response) {
            var cartHtml = "";
            if (response.data.length > 0) {
              $.each(response.data, function(key, item) {
                productId = item[0];
                var productImg = item[4];
                var productName = item[1];
                var productQty = item[2];
                var productPrice = parseFloat(item[3]).toFixed(2);
                var productTotal = parseFloat(item[3] * item[2]).toFixed(2);
                var deleteBtn = item[5];

                var qtyInput = '<input id="qtyInput" class=" text-center" type="number" min="1" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" style="width:50px;" id="qty_value" name="qty_value" value="' + productQty + '"><input type="hidden" id="productId" value="' + productId + '">'
                cartHtml += '<tr><td><img src="../admin/img/product_images/' + productImg + '" style="width:50px"/></td><td>' + productName + '</td><td>' + productPrice + '</td><td>' + productTotal + '</td><td>' + qtyInput + '</td><td>' + deleteBtn + '</td></tr>';
              });
              $("#cart-items-table").html(cartHtml);

              $("#sub-total").html(response.subTotal.toFixed(2));
              $("#grand-total").html(response.grandTotal.toFixed(2));

              // event binding for updateQty function
              $('#cart-items-table').on('keyup', '#qtyInput', function() {
                var pId = $(this).siblings("#productId").val();
                var qty = $(this).val();
                updateQty(pId, qty);
              });
            } else {
              cartHtml = '<div class="text-center"> <h4> Your Cart is Empty</h4></div>';
              $("#cart-table-html").html(cartHtml);
            }


            $("#cart_qty").html(response.totalCartQty);
            $("#cart_qty1").html(response.totalCartQty);
          } // /success
        }); // /ajax
  }
```

I hope you could help me. Thank you so much

Comment: That’s not PHP, that’s JavaScript

Comment: That's why you need to do validation

Comment: the min"1" is not working

Comment: I have removed three of the five tags you used. The rest of your site may use PHP, Ajax, and jQuery, but none of the code shown does.

Comment: yes because that elements is on the cart of the website, and it also using ajax

Comment: @IMSoP hello siir, I updated the code, I included the ajax

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="number" min=1 max=1000>
```

Definitely, it will work. Tryit